# Can I insert textboxes and preserve blank space?

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a pre-formatted report in Reporting Services 2005, and I need to change it to insert a series of textboxes (some static some using data) at various places in the report.

Can I do this and keep all the rest of the spacing the same?

So I have:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc


ddd
eee
```

And I want to insert a new textbox below ccc but maintain the spacing above ddd without having to move ddd, eee, and anything below them:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
zzzzz


ddd
eee
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd move the textboxes below.  However, you can add "zzzzz," set CanGrow to true, and give it a height of 0in.  When it grows, it'll push everything else down.

Comment: +1 for the advice.  I think I'll start at the bottom and move everything down manually.  I want to insert a gap of 0.25in and have everything adjust itself in lots of places - CanGrow will just knock things out by a few pixels every now and then and remove the granular placement.